# Using the display intent on a page of a wearable notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, wear-os

I create a wearable compatible notification with a second page which should embedd a custom activity (on the wearable).

Here is the relevant part of the Manifest from the wearable app:

```xml
<activity android:name=".Test"
          android:label="aaa"
          android:allowEmbedded="true"
          android:taskAffinity=""
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is my related android code from the phone:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
notificationIntent.setClassName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".wear.Main");
PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Bitmap bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_wearable);
Notification test = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Message")
        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
            .setBackground(bg)
            .addPage(new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Page 1")
                .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                    .setDisplayIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                    .setCustomSizePreset(NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.SIZE_FULL_SCREEN)
                ).build()
            )
        )
        .build();
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(12345, test);
```

Do you have any idea why this don't work on the phone, but on the wearable itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create and issue custom notifications with embedded activities from the wearable itself.

From the docs:

> You can only create and issue custom notifications on the wearable,
>   and the system does not sync these notifications to the handheld.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#CustomNotifications)